# How does this RSSI vs Distance equation work?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, signal-processing

I came across this equation in a [research paper](http://www.ijitee.org/attachments/File/v2i2/A0359112112.pdf), and can't seem to make sense of it.  Let me give an argument for why it doesn't make sense, and perhaps someone can tell me where my flaw is?

$$ P_L(d_i) [dB] = P_L(d_0) [dB] + 10n\log_{10}\left(\frac{d_i}{d_0}\right) $$

$P_L(d_0)$ is the RSSI value for distance 0

$ P_L(d_i)$ is the RSSI value for distance 1

$d_0$ is distance 0

$d_i$ is distance 1

and RSSI is the *received signal strength indicator*. So if you put the two RSSI values on the left side of the equation, you have:

$$ \text{RSSI}_1 - \text{RSSI}_0 = 10n\log \left(\frac{\text{Dist}_1}{\text{Dist}_0}\right) $$

Let's consider the case when distance 1 is larger than distance 0:

(Dist 1) > (Dist 0)

Greater distance means less RSSI, so (RSSI 1) < (RSSI 0).  So the left side of the equation is negative.  The research paper states that $n$ is normally between 2 and 4, so the $10n$ part of the right side of the equation is positive, which means the log value must be negative, right?

But that leads to a contradiction.  We said Dist 1 is greater, so the number inside the log is greater than 1, therefore the log value itself is positive.  So intuitively, we have found an equation with the left side negative and the right side positive.  What's going on??

(The opposite leads to a contradiction too: if dist 1 is less than dist 0, we get the left side positive and the right side negative)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't my area, but the notation $P_L(d_i) [dB]$ suggests that it's using units of decibels i.e. if $P_i$ is the power at distance $d_i$ in Watts then:

$$ P_L(d_i) [dB] = 10\log_{10}\left(\frac{P_i}{P_\text{ref}}\right) $$

for some reference power $P_\text{ref}$. Then rearranging the equation as you suggest gives:

$$ 10\log_{10}\left(\frac{P_i}{P_0}\right) = 10n\log_{10}\left(\frac{d_i}{d_0}\right) $$

or:

$$ \frac{P_i}{P_0} = \left(\frac{d_i}{d_0}\right)^n $$

If you put $n$ in as $-2$ then this is just a statement of the inverse square law, which is exactly what you'd expect for some signal propagating isotropically in space. I note the paper does use the phrase:

> the known pathloss exponent $n$ without **assuming it to be 2 as in free space**

which supports this interpretation. So I would guess $n$ is really negative, and the paper is talking about the magnitude of $n$ while ignoring its sign.